# Connect web part to list on separate Sharepoint Instance

Tags: 2010, external-list

As part of a migration process, I'd like to have a list view on the new environment(SP2010 standard) that's connected to a list in the previous environment(WSS 3). So different servers, site collections, etc. The user accounts are the same and Kerberos is configured and working correctly.

If this is possible what combinations of Web Parts and data sources do I need to achieve this?

Comment: How interactive does the data in 2010 need to be?  Is simply read-only sufficient or do you need to update the WSS3 data from 2010 as well?

Answer (score 1):

As the simplest solution - can you simply set up page viewer web part and create simplified page layout for list view webpart in WSS to use in it? :)

Comment: That would work, but I want to be able to experiment with new page design in the new site, not duplicate the original. I'd prefer to have it display the actual up-to-date content if possible.

Comment: If you want to use SP 2010 webparts the only option I can thinf about is to use BCS external list and to implement BCS connector to WSS list via WSS web services.